# Pyspark.pandas PandasNotImplementedError: The method `pd.Series.__iter__()` is not implemented. If you want to collect your data as an NumPy array

Tags: pandas, pyspark, databricks, pyspark-pandas, spark-koalas

I am new in Pyspark. I am using pyspark.pandas and want to test how it can be used with scipy library. I've got a really basic code of scipy and pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
from scipy.stats import pearsonr

# Example data
data = {
    'Age': [23, 45, 34, 65, 34, 29, 40],
    'Day_of_Week': ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Assigning numerical values for the days of the week
days_of_week = {'Monday': 1, 'Tuesday': 2, 'Wednesday': 3, 'Thursday': 4, 'Friday': 5, 'Saturday': 6, 'Sunday': 7}
df['Day_of_Week_num'] = df['Day_of_Week'].map(days_of_week)

# Calculating Pearson correlation
corr, _ = pearsonr(df['Age'], df['Day_of_Week_num'])
print('Pearson correlation coefficient:', corr)
```

When I changed "pandas" to "pyspark.pandas", I received an error.

`PandasNotImplementedError: The method pd.Series.__iter__() is not implemented. If you want to collect your data as an NumPy array.`

I encountered an issue after changing "pandas" to "pyspark.pandas". I came across a similar problem in this [PandasNotImplementedError: The method `pd.Series.__iter__()` is not implemented. If you want to collect your data as an NumPy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69382610/pandasnotimplementederror-the-method-pd-series-iter-is-not-implemented). However, the person applied the function over the entire dataframe, and not on the pyspark.pandas.Series. As far as I know, `pd.Series.__iter__()` is not implemented because it requires collecting the data to a single node, (such as iterating over a Series) . Therefore, I'm not sure if it is possible to implement scipy.stats.pearsonr on pyspark.pandas.Series.